# Exception thrown importing swampy.Gui

Tags: python, python-2.7, spyder

i'm trying to import swampy.gui module using Spyder, but gets error.

input:

```
from swampy.Gui import *
```

output:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Sharon Tarrab/Desktop/ex9_012345678.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sharon Tarrab/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-102-9d4bbf99fee6>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Sharon Tarrab/Desktop/ex9_012345678.py', wdir='C:/Users/Sharon Tarrab/Desktop')


  File "C:\Users\Sharon Tarrab\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Sharon Tarrab/Desktop/ex9_012345678.py", line 1, in <module>
from swampy.Gui import *
ImportError: No module named swampy.Gui
```

what is the problem? is there any chance to add this module?

Comment: This is missing the actual exception itself. It should be next to the stack trace included (which, unfortunately, isn't of much help).

Comment: Ahh -- that's much better. Can you `import swampy` at all, or is it only the gui module missing?

Comment: Also, I'd strongly suggest speaking to how you _installed_ `swampy`, and why you believe it to be present on your local machine. (Can you import swampy.Gui in a different kind of window, but not IPython?)

Comment: (If you have more than one Python environment on your machine, be sure the one you installed Swampy in is the same one you're running IPython against).

Comment: ...specifically, the environment you're using here is one provided by Anaconda, so that's where you need Swampy installed. Be sure that when you run "python setup.py install" for Swampy, that Python is the one from Anaconda.